# MAMP MySql Master Slave Replication on local machine

Tags: mysql-replication

Has anyone got a good tutorial or info how to make a master slave replication on a local machine with MAMP 2.0?

Should I install multiple MySQL instances or can I do it with one installation?

Thanks

Answer (score 1):

You need to have multiple MySQL instances to do replication.